# Jasper Report not streamed correctly in PDF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, pdf, jasper-reports

I am generating a PDF invoice with JR. On my local machine (linux ubuntu) works perfectly:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        String templateAbsolutePath = ec.getRealPath(templateRelativePath);

        JasperReport jasperReport;
        try {
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(templateAbsolutePath);        
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, getParametriFattura(fattura), datasource );

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, ec.getResponseOutputStream());

        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fc.responseComplete();
```

However, when I deployed my war to the staging server (linux ubuntu) it shows that:

[image]

I suppose it's a trivial problem, but where can I start from?

*I deliberately omitted configurations, system details and so on... because I don't know what can be useful.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the webbrowser that it's a PDF file, not a (X)HTML file.

```
ec.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
```

Note: this needs to be set *before* any bit is written to the response body.